# Add label field after input radio button through jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, label

My CMS generates the next code:

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <label for="pa_period">period</label>
            </td>
            <td class="value">
                <fieldset> 
                    <strong>Choose An Option...</strong><br />
                    <input type="radio" value="today" id="pa_period" name="attribute_pa_period">today<br />
                    <input type="radio" value="tomorrow" id="pa_period" name="attribute_pa_period">tomorrow<br />
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <label for="pa_version">version</label>
            </td>
            <td class="value">
                <fieldset> 
                    <strong>Choose An Option...</strong><br />
                    <input type="radio" value="inoffice" id="pa_version" name="attribute_pa_version">in office<br />
                    <input type="radio" value="bymail" id="pa_version" name="attribute_pa_version">by mail<br />
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see this output does not contain code 'label' for text after input.
I've tried to use code

```
$('fieldset strong').remove();
$('fieldset br').remove();
$('label').remove();
var text = $.trim($('fieldset').text());
var te = text.split("\n");
$('fieldset :radio, fieldset :checkbox').each(function (i) {
    $(this).after('<label for="' + this.id + '">' + te[i] + '</label>');
});
var child = $('fieldset').children('input,label');
$('fieldset').html(child);
```

But this cod does not work (I'm new in jquery)

Edited... Thanks to @charlietfl .
My result code for Woocommerce Radio Buttons Plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-radio-buttons/ )

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('fieldset strong').remove();
$('fieldset br').remove();
var $nodes = $('fieldset').contents();
$nodes.each(function (i) {
if ($(this).is('input')) {
this.id = this.id+i;              
var nextNode = $nodes[i + 1];
if (nextNode && nextNode.nodeType == 3) {
var label = '<label for="' + this.id + '">' + nextNode.textContent + '</label>';
$(nextNode).replaceWith(label);
}
}
}); 
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the HTML structure you're trying to create with jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, what is your desired output?

Comment: Why are you doing this client-side? This feels (though I may be wrong) like a problem that would be better solved server-side when the `<form>` is being generated. Incidentally, what does "*this [code] does not work*" mean, exactly? In what way does it "*not work*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses `contents()` so you can check for text nodes that follow an input and replace just those text nodes

```
var $nodes = $('fieldset').contents();

$nodes.each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).is('input')) {
        var nextNode = $nodes[i + 1];
        if (nextNode && nextNode.nodeType == 3) {
            var label = '<label for="' + this.id + '">' + nextNode.textContent + '</label>';
            $(nextNode).replaceWith(label);
        }
    }
});
```

You could also modify the `input` selector to include `textarea` and `select` by using `:input`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2kkgamw5/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your array of text is not what you expect

```
["today", "                    ", 
 "                    tomorrow", 
 "                    ", 
 "                 ", 
 "", "                    ", 
 "                    in office", 
 "                    ", 
 "                    by mail"]
```

You can use

```
te=te.filter(function(str){
  return $.trim(str)!="";
});
```

```js
$('fieldset strong').remove();
$('fieldset br').remove();
$('label').remove();
var text = $.trim($('fieldset').text());
var te = text.split("\n");
te=te.filter(function(str){
    return $.trim(str)!="";
});
$('fieldset :radio, fieldset :checkbox').each(function (i) {
    $(this).after('<label for="' + this.id + '">' + te[i] + '</label>');
});
var child = $('fieldset').children('input,label');
$('fieldset').html(child);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <label for="pa_period">period</label>
            </td>
            <td class="value">
                <fieldset> <strong>Choose An Option...</strong>

                    <br />
                    <input type="radio" value="today" id="pa_period" name="attribute_pa_period" />today
                    <br />
                    <input type="radio" value="tomorrow" id="pa_period" name="attribute_pa_period" />tomorrow
                    <br />
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <label for="pa_version">version</label>
            </td>
            <td class="value">
                <fieldset> <strong>Choose An Option...</strong>

                    <br />
                    <input type="radio" value="inoffice" id="pa_version" name="attribute_pa_version">in office
                    <br />
                    <input type="radio" value="bymail" id="pa_version" name="attribute_pa_version">by mail
                    <br />
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```